# R cannot be resolved to a variable - cannot find source of layout error

Tags: android

I modified a working, error-free project and got the error - R cannot be resolved to a variable. My R file is not getting generated. I keep getting this error in my layout xml -

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' 
with value '@string/show_anwser_button')
```

Layout has -

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showAnswerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/show_answer_button" />
```

This happens despite putting an entry in res/values/strings.xml as -

```
<string name="show_answer_button">Show Answer</string>
```

I tried to build my project again, but it did not help. I tried a couple of more answers on SO and they did not work.

I don't know where I am making a mistake. I need help to fix it.

EDIT - When i try to clean my project only, i get the error -

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Package Builder' on project 'GeoQuiz'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete '/GeoQuiz/bin/res'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: C:\workspace - Android\GeoQuiz\bin\res\crunch.
Could not delete: C:\workspace - Android\GeoQuiz\bin\res.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Could not delete '/GeoQuiz/bin/res'.
Problems encountered while deleting resources.
Problems encountered while deleting files.
Could not delete: C:\workspace - Android\GeoQuiz\bin\res\crunch.
Could not delete: C:\workspace - Android\GeoQuiz\bin\res.
```

Comment: clean your project and check if there is any error in your `res` folder or not

Comment: @praveenSharma - yes, the error is caused by the layout xml in res/layout. but i don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: on which line you have error still..

Comment: @praveenSharma - Eclipse, is great but strange. It causes the error i mentioned above. Then, contents of only gen vanish. I build project again and the problem is solved. In a nutshell - Clean > Ignore clean error > Build project again > problem solved.

Comment: delete the R.java manually and let it create automatically

Comment: yes sometime it happens , so use clean project before compiling if you have any error

Comment: yes...sometimes it's that behavior. In those cases, close and exit your eclipse and start fresh compiling through Project --> Clean. Check if you still have any errors. As in your case here..it should be through cleanly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:text="@string/show_anwser_button" />

anwser != answer should be

there is typo :)

After that clean and build the project

Comment: Yes, I fixed that and the error still did not go after building the project.

Answer (score 0):

Search all your layout files for

```
show_anwser_button
```

Change it to

```
show_answer_button
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed that and the error still did not go after building the project.

Comment: Make sure you have Build Automatically enabled in Eclipse. Then choose Clean Project and clean all projects. (if you use eclipse). Post your new error message.

Comment: Not necessary. I am not sure if that would be helpful.